# UITapGestureRecognizer for a custom cell in UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer, didselectrowatindexpath

In my iPhone application, I am using a `UITableView` with custom table cells by subclassing `UITableViewCell`. Let's assume my custom cell class name as *ItemTableViewCell*. The relevant *ItemTableViewCell.xib* has a subview of `UIView` with the name of ***infoView***.

I want that *infoView* identify single tap/touch it gets. If it is just a tap, I can do it by adding `UITapGestureRecognizer` using story board and having a action method for that. But what I need is while identify the tap/touch of infoView, I need to pass the relevant table row info to the target method/selector.

If I further explain the situation, `UITableView` consists of `NSArray` of `UITableViewCell`. That custom cell has a bottom bar with a subview called *infoView*. By tapping/touching that *infoView* it should call a method with the related NSArray element as parameter. By tap/touching the rest of the cell, it should call `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method as normal.

Comment: Use the delegation pattern to have your cell inform the controller when it's tapped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have found a solution. While I'm creating custom cells, I'm adding UITapGestureRecognizer to the relevant UIVIew (in my case it's infoView) like below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tappedOnInfoView:)];
[tap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
[tap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
[cell.infoView addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[cell.infoView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
[cell.infoView setTag:realIndex];
```

As you can see from the last line, I'm passing the cell index rather than the cell data to the selector which will fire after identify tap gesture.

At the same time I'm maintaining an NSMutableArray to store data of the cell. As you can understand, there will be simultaneous NSArray elements for each cell index.

This is how my selector appears;

```
- (void)tappedOnInfoView:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
```

By using below code you can get the index related to the tap guesture occured

```
sender.view.tag
```

Using follow code snippet I'm able to get the details of cell where I've store in a NSMutableArray

```
[myMutArray objectAtIndex:sender.view.tag];
```

Mission accomplished :)

Answer (score 0):

Implement gesture action in Tableview SuperClass. Or You can use Custom delegate in UITableViewCell subclass. In UITableView Subclass declare a protocol.

```
@protocol customCellDelegate <NSObject>

@required
-(void)selectedCellInIndexPath : (NSIndexPath *)indexpath;
@end
```

Set this property in UITableView Subclass

```
@property (nonatomic, strong)NSIndexPath *indexpath;
@property (nonatomic, strong) id <customCellDelegate> delegate;
```

And then in Your UITableView Subclass gesture action add This lines

```
if(self.delegate){
   [self.delegate selectedCellInIndexPath: self.indexpath];
}
```

And in your tableview datasource method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Implement this code

```
cell.delegate = (id)self;
cell.indexpath = indexPath;
```

And in Uitableview super class just implement this method

```
-(void)selectedCellInIndexPath : (NSIndexPath *)indexpath{
//display uiimagepickercontroller modally or anything else here
}
```